# Is there a way to access entry point class object from other classes of the app?

Tags: actionscript-3, global, entry-point

Just wonder if I can reference entry point object from any place in the app? Is it maybe assigned to some global object, like stage is for example?

Currently I use static methods and variables, but this breaks encapsulation.

Comment: Do you mean the DocumentClass/"Main"-class used to start your application?

Comment: Well... not sure how to name it. Basically the one that is marked as default Application.

Comment: Hmm.. is there any specific need you have? The entry point is otherwise just a regular object, thus you can pass it around like everything else.

Comment: I know that I can pass it around. I just wondered if there is some shortcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `someObject` is in display list, then you have a `someObject.root` reference which is what you are looking for. If you remove `someObject` from display list, you loose that reference.

My answer is no, there is no direct way to access entry object, and there shouldn't be: that's what incapsulation is about. Accessing something globally is pretty much AS1 way. When you access main instance by implicitly referencing MainClass, you make parts of your application tightly coupled, which is generally bad.

However, if you do need to have it, you may choose from several options.

- Use static var: `MainClass.instance`
- Use singletone-like access through `MainClass.getInstance()`
- Create a package-level variable or a package level getter method

I would choose the latter.

```
package com.smth.application 
{
    public var mainObject:MainClass;
} 

// in main app
package com.smth.application 
{
    public function MainClass()
    {
        mainObject = this;
    }
}
```

It may look somewhat similar to static acces, but I think this way your code will retain some flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

`stage` is a reference to the top level of your application, which you can access though any display object that is on the display tree as `myDisplayObject.stage`.  When using a custom document class, it will be the first child (index 0) of `stage`, unless you manually force something else into the 0 index as Bakapii says.

Comment: Actually the DocumentClass is the first child of `stage`, it is not the `stage` itself. This is also only true when you first start the Application, since it's possible to do something like this `someClass.stage.addChildAt(someOtherClass, 0);`

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that. I shall amend.

Comment: It's `root`, not the `stage`. You don't need to rely on display list order. Try this, for instance: `trace(stage.contains(root), getQualifiedClassName(root));`. And from any display object that is added to display list: `trace(getQualifiedClassName(someObject.root));`. However, I don't think this answers the question, because jayarjo wants to access main object from "any place in the app".